# Liferay Documents and Media - Document title localization

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'd like to localize "title" attribute of images administered in Document and Media library (at least the title, the description should also be localized).

My scenario:

- To add images to Documents and Media library
- To display the images on a page using Media Gallery portlet
- To see localized title of the images

Media Gallery portlet renders the image previews with their title. The problem is the title, which is not localized.

The question is, how can I localize the title?

The same applies for folders and their names - How can I localize them?

Version - Liferay 6.2 CE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the following approach (in Liferay 6.2).

Whenever the localization is needed, I prefer to create journal articles with document attachments (possibly with custom structure).

The journal articles fully support localization and some other useful features like publication scheduling.